# How do I declare a NUL character in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'd like to write a string literal that includes the NUL character. How do I do this in Dart?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 8):

Use a unicode escape:

```
void main() {
   print('Hello\u0000World');
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `\x` escpae: `"Hello\x00World"`.